# .net OracleConnection Keyword not supported: 'proxy user id'

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm trying to connect to Oracle 11 DB using .net class OracleConnection.

```
string connectionString = "User Id=user1;Password=user1;" + 
"Data Source=oracle;Proxy User Id=PROXY;Proxy Password=PROXY; ";
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
```

What I'm getting is

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'proxy user id'.
```

According to the oracle documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featConnecting.htm#i1006514 proxy user connection should be supported by OracleConnection class.

What am I missing?

I'm on VS2012, .NET 4.5

Thanks in advance,
Denis.